# How can I modify an AD attribute through VBS, using a variable as the username object for PUT?

Tags: vbscript

I know the title is kind of confusing.  Here's a snippet of the current code:

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo") 

On Error Resume Next
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
comp=oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ComputerName%")

Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.Username) 
user = WScript.Arguments.Named("current_user")
Set objUser = user

total = Now & " - " & comp

objUser.Put "info", total
objUser.SetInfo
```

The purpose of this script (modified from someone else's script) is to update an AD user's "notes" attribute with the timestamp and computer name.  I've also set up a scheduled task to do this on unlock, so it can give us a real-time picture of users all over our environment.

I'm passing the variable "user" from a batch file that reads the CURRENT user, based on the CONSOLE session's explorer.exe process.  I need this user to be used for the PUT action at the end of this vbs script.

How can I do that?

I've tried directly setting it, as you can see in the script.  I've also tried doing the same thing, but commenting this out:

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.Username)
```

Nothing seems to work.
Any ideas are appreciated!  Thanks!